# Finding minimum double attribute in array of objects

Tags: java

I'm fairly certain I know what is going wrong here, I just don't know how to fix this. In each iteration of the for loop, `minval` is compared against the next element the array and updated because the next one is larger each time. How do I save the `minval` to be compared each time?

```
    public static double findMinVolume(Solids[]x,int xlast){
        int i = 0;
        double minval = 0;
        for(i=0;i<=xlast-1;i++){
            if (minval < x[i].getVolume())
                minval = x[i].getVolume();
        }
        return minval;
```

Comment: Change `double minval = 0;` to `double minval = Double.MAX_VALUE;`

Comment: And you want to update it when `minval >`, not `<`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `Double.MAX_VALUE` in Java (you're thinking of C#), but otherwise correct.

Comment: And `int i` is conventionally declared inside the `for` header. And `i<=xlast-1` can be simplified to `i < xlast`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Darn. And I've had my coffee this morning, although you'd never know it. Thanks for catching and correcting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"... In each iteration of the for loop, `minval` is compared against the next element the array and updated because the next one is larger each time. ..."*

Your values are incorrect.
Initialize *minval* to the first value, and start *i* at 1.

```java
public static double findMinVolume(Solids[]x,int xlast){
    int i = 0;
    double minval = x[0].getVolume();
    for(i=1;i<=xlast-1;i++){
        if (minval < x[i].getVolume())
            minval = x[i].getVolume();
    }
    return minval;
}
```

Alternately, you can stream *x*, utilizing the *[limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long))*, *[mapToDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction))* and *[min](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#min())* methods.

```java
public static double findMinVolume(Solids[]x,int xlast){
    return
        Stream.of(x)
              .limit(xlast - 1)
              .mapToDouble(Solids::getVolume)
              .min()
              .getAsDouble();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I may implement the stream though I'm not sure. Any idea how I can use the same kind of function but return a string getter which is also the lowest volume object? I'm trying to just insert it in the for loop but it's not working the way I expected

Comment: nevermind figured it out

Comment: @ThomasHutton, you can convert the returning _double_ value to a _String_ with the _[String#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(double))_ method.